# React Google Maps Unable to set scroll zoom off

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I have been trying to set the zoom on scroll param to off, but having no luck in turing the feature off.

I am using react-google-maps component. Linked below.

https://github.com/sohilpandya/Bidlt/blob/master/src/js/components/builder/overview-google-map.js

Would appreciate it if someone can cast an eye on it and help me figure out where to put the zoomscroll to off.

Answer (score 9):

Solved it by putting the `scrollwheel:false` as an option for GoogleMap component as such

`<GoogleMap options={{ scrollwheel: false}}>`

Answer (score 2):

The best solution here is to set 
`<GoogleMap options={{ gestureHandling: 'none'}}>`

If you also want to hide the +/- zoom buttons you can add an additional option
`<GoogleMap options={{ gestureHandling: 'none', disableDefaultUI: true}}>`

Documentation for scrollwheel option:
`Note: This property is not recommended. To disable zooming using scrollwheel, you can use the gestureHandling property, and set it to either "cooperative" or "none"`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.scrollwheel

Answer (score 0):

To hide "use ctrl + scroll to zoom map" in React js put  `options={{ gestureHandling: "greedy" }}>` in

```
<GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={15}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 44.814346, lng: 20.458047 }}
        options={{ gestureHandling: "greedy" }}>
        <Marker position={{ lat: 44.814346, lng: 20.458047 }} />
</GoogleMap>
```